# What does $g^{a}{}_{b}$ mean in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm having a hard time getting a grasp of what $g^{a}{}_{b}$ truly means in GR. I understand that somehow it is the metric tensor in a sense, but I don't know its properties. I have some wild guesses about it, but I'm really not sure.

Is it just the metric tensor with one index pulled up by the inverse metric ($g^{a}{}_{b}=g^{a\mu}g_{\mu b}$)? If yes, what are its properties?

Is it Correct to say that it is a tensor of type (1,1) (since the one upper and one lower index)? If yes, how can I imagine that it is a linear map from a vector space to itself?

I couldn't answers to my questions on the internet, so thanks in advance for replying!

Comment: Its same as $\delta^a_b$ which is nothing but components of identity matrix

Comment: Does [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511630/) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between $g^{\alpha\beta}$ and $g^\alpha_{\space\space\beta}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511630/)

Comment: Yes, thank you all!